# Extract longitude and latitude from shapefile

Tags: shapefile, convert

I want to create a media wiki page with map option where polygon required the following format. What is name of this format and how can it possible to extract this format from shapefile?

`polygons=62.103882522897855,5.09765625:58.309488840677645,5.712890625:58.95000823335702,10.8984375:61.68987220046001,12.83203125:63.35212928507874,11.865234375:64.1297836764257,13.974609375`

Detailed format can be found here

http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Maps_examples/Google_Maps_shapes

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps#Map_projection

Answer (score 1):

Can you write python? If so then use shapely and Fiona  to extract that information from a shapefile.

Fiona - wraps the OGR libraries in a Pythonic way - pip install Fiona
Shapely - provides Pythonic style bindings to GEOS - pip install Shapely

Here is a github repo where I show some basic usage of shapely and fiona
https://github.com/thesteve0/shapefileconverter

If you are a Java fan you can use JTS.

You could also use ogr2ogr to export your shapefiles to JSON or XML and work with it from there.